# changing dtypes of structured/record arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Q1. When recasting a column to a different data type, is `np.array` or `np.astype` preferred? I've seen examples using `np.astype` but both seem to return the desired result (both return copies of the original array).

```
import numpy as np

## recasting string to integer
x = np.rec.array([('a','1'),('b','2')],names='col1,col2')
##
In []: x
Out[]: 
rec.array([('a', '1'), ('b', '2')], 
      dtype=[('col1', '|S1'), ('col2', '|S1')])
##
dt = x.dtype.descr
dt[1] = (dt[1][0],'int')
## which is more appropriate:
y = np.array(x,dtype=dt)
## or
y = x.astype(dt)
## ?
In []: y
Out[]: 
rec.array([('a', 1), ('b', 2)], 
      dtype=[('col1', '|S1'), ('col2', '<i4')])
```

Q2. Renaming columns: integer columns become zero when calling `np.array`, but retains its values with `np.rec.array`. Why? My understanding is that with the former, you get a structured array and the latter returns a record array; for most purposes I thought they were the same. And this behavior is surprising, in any case.

```
## rename 2nd column from col2 to v2
dt = copy.deepcopy(y.dtype)
names = list(dt.names)
names[1] = 'v2'
dt.names = names
## this is not right
newy = np.array(y,dtype=dt)
In []: newy
Out[]: 
array([('a', 0), ('b', 0)], 
      dtype=[('col1', '|S1'), ('v2', '<i4')])
## this is correct
newy = np.rec.array(y,dtype=dt)
In []: newy
Out[]: 
rec.array([('a', 1), ('b', 2)], 
      dtype=[('col1', '|S1'), ('v2', '<i4')])
```

Answer (score 3):

**Q1**:  Both the `np.array` and `np.astype` approaches do the same work in the same way under-the-hood.  Using `np.astype` involves a little less typing, and it is more clear to the reader that the intention is to change the datatype.

Comment: Thanks! That is surprising, given the Zen of Python... “There should be one – and preferably only one – obvious way to do it.” When I have more points I will come back and upvote...