# Changing dtype of structured array zeros out string data

Tags: python, numpy

My question is essentially what is asked (and not answered) in 'Q2' of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941591/changing-dtypes-of-structured-record-arrays?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

I have a structured array with a column of strings and a column of integers. I replace the strings with integers using a dict, but because the type of that column is unchanged, the integers are recorded as strings. I can change the dtype of the column to be integer, but then all the strings are converted to 0, instead of the integer values in each string. How can I change the column such that the integer values aren't lost during the dtype conversion?

I created an illustrative example:

```
dat = np.array([('1', 3392),('2', 4159),('1', 1093),('1', 9836)], dtype=[('code', 'U24'),('id', 'i2')])
dat.astype(dtype=[('code', 'i4'), ('id', 'i2')])
```

But for reasons I can't understand, this actually works, yielding:

```
array([(1, 3392), (2, 4159), (1, 1093), (1, 9836)], 
  dtype=[('code', '<i4'), ('id', '<i2')])
```

This is what I want! Instead, for some reason, I'm getting the equivalent of:

```
array([(0, 3392), (0, 4159), (0, 1093), (0, 9836)], 
  dtype=[('code', '<i4'), ('id', '<i2')])
```

What could cause all the 'code' values to be zeroed out like that, if in fact, that's not the expected result from `ndarray.astype`? Thanks. (In case it's relevant, I'm using Python 3.)

**EDIT:** Here's a snapshot of the actual data, after processing with the dict.

```
array([('1', 2814), ('1', 1185), ('1', 6836), ('2', 7057), ('1', 5403),...

   ('1', 1642), ('1', 3967), ('2', 7982), ('1', 6139), ('1', 9934),
   ('2', 9932), ('1', 3044), ('1', 2769)], 
  dtype=[('name', '<U24'), ('id', '<i2')])
```

Comment: Example failure data?

Comment: I can't share the original data or the actual dict I used for privacy reasons, but I edited the original question with a chunk of the data after running it through the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're doing this:

```
baddata = numpy.array([('1', 2814), ('1', 1185), ('1', 6836), ('2', 7057), ('1', 5403),
   ('1', 1642), ('1', 3967), ('2', 7982), ('1', 6139), ('1', 9934),
   ('2', 9932), ('1', 3044), ('1', 2769)], 
  dtype=[('name', '<U24'), ('id', '<i2')])

baddata.astype([('code', 'i4')])
#>>> array([(0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,),
#>>>        (0,), (0,)], 
#>>>       dtype=[('code', '<i4')])
```

When you're meant to be doing this:

```
baddata = numpy.array([('1', 2814), ('1', 1185), ('1', 6836), ('2', 7057), ('1', 5403),
   ('1', 1642), ('1', 3967), ('2', 7982), ('1', 6139), ('1', 9934),
   ('2', 9932), ('1', 3044), ('1', 2769)], 
  dtype=[('name', '<U24'), ('id', '<i2')])

baddata.astype([('name', 'i4')])
#>>> array([(1,), (1,), (1,), (2,), (1,), (1,), (1,), (2,), (1,), (1,), (2,),
#>>>        (1,), (1,)], 
#>>>       dtype=[('name', '<i4')])
```

*Note the names*.

Comment: You're absolutely right. When I was using `ndarray.astype`, I was changing the type to string _and_ changing the column name at the same time. The original dtype was: `[('name', 'U24'), ('id', 'i2')]` and I was trying to change the dtype to: `[('type', 'i4'), ('id', 'i2')]`. That being said, is there a particular reason why the column name and data type can't be changed simultaneously?

Comment: I don't understand how you're "changing" the name. The name refers to a column, when you "change" the name you're actually discarding the old column and initialising a new one. Try `baddata.astype([('foo', '<U24'), ('id', '<i2')])` for an example.

Comment: Both the mistake and the question arise from a lack of fundamental understanding of what dtype is doing, but now I know better. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @Veedrac, I am getting - when changing just the only field type via your test-conde - "baddata.astype([('name', 'i4')]) - I am getting error: "ValueError: structures must have the same size. Do I something wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: @VilemRousi idk, sorry